What have I misconfigured for mail server in regards to MX record?
Hello and happy holidays,
Have a mail server mail.giftbutton.com, which is receiving and sending mails. The problem is it has no MX record, accroding to https://mxtoolbox.com and https://www.mail-tester.com/ test.
DNS records are:
A   @   51.89.216.247
A   mail    146.59.32.248
MX  @   mail.giftbutton.com. (Priority: 10)
TXT dkim._domainkey.mail v=DKIM1;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwUBorg14HW4dVb61hgTPKhGBaef2Qn7R5arBSmKitKqL2wySVUn3TIRd1DGqDG00TEAPhMkvzexm680y5OEV+lYlmBh/EZNrinYUZToL61vp4tKt690YbI3EuaJcIZryT40eGg8JWMmL6CvAwrRh2lC7ynhmqC1u8YfXiN/hJ7U7GUMrJWnXzKqDytqPkwPstnxwlYwPY+picMBtqqp7gWhmoSROj5vu47XROg3V1THEw7d5tmpEPbTx26+NRstxE9Gg6bJWpjkfdA4545LQh2Ykv4elChyMlnTwCbcS4ySfiQpK1/0zhnylxzcPeZGpw1TNWciX7rd0BbAYOQMDBQIDAQAB
TXT mail v=spf1 ip4:146.59.32.248 ip6:2001:41d0:601:1100::5a97 ~all
TXT _dmarc.mail v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarcreports@mail.giftbutton.com;

What have I misconfigured?
Any ideas very appreciated.
Update: this is the report mail-tester.com is returning:
 [SPF] Your server 146.59.32.248 is authorized to use info@mail.giftbutton.com
 Your DKIM signature is valid
 Your message passed the DMARC test
 Your server 146.59.32.248 is successfully associated with mail.giftbutton.com
 We didn't find a mail server (MX Record) behind your domain name mail.giftbutton.com.

Why mail-tester.com not seeing MX record for mail.giftbutton.com if it exists?
As someone here explained a while ago, sending mail from a subdomain is better than from a domain. If a user had a bad day and marks notification email as spam, the spam points will accumulate for the subdomain. This won't affect other subdomains - such as accounts.giftbutton.com.
What do I need to change in DNS config to full pass the spamminess check?

If the server is receiving messages, then the mail records are configured correctly.

Nothing is misconfigured. MXToolbox correctly reports that there is an MX set for giftbutton.com, but complains that you have no DKIM/DMARC records. If you ask it about SPF records, it says that none of those are set either. Remember that you are looking for the MX for giftbutton.com, not the MX for mail.giftbutton.com, as you're sending mail from the domain, not from the mail subdomain.
Edit: As per the first comment below, the question has been significantly changed, so I'll do the same to the answer here. But the root cause is still the same: there is no MX record for the subdomain. The line
MX  @   mail.giftbutton.com. (Priority: 10)

in the code above specifies that the Mail eXchanger for the root domain @ is mail.giftbutton.com. You would need a second record for the subdomain
MX  mail mail.giftbutton.com. (Priority: 10)

But as a way to avoid being marked and blocked as spam, that would be useless, as almost every spam block service works on IP address rather than domain / subdomain. You'd actually want to use a separate mail server on a separate IP for that to work the way you want.

Please see the update.

@jurijus01 answer updated to match.
